# Importing CSV files in PHP when imported text contains bullet points

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a simple code that imports CSV files ;

```
function readInputFromFile($file)
{
   $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
   while (!feof($fh))
   {
      $ln = fgetcsv($fh);

      $ln = array_implode($ln);
      $parts[] = $ln;
   }

   fclose($fh);

   return $parts;
}

function array_implode($a)
{
  // print detailed info if $a is not array
  if(!is_array($a)) {
    //var_dump($a); // what is in $a
    //var_dump(debug_backtrace()); // where exactly was it called?
    //exit;
  } else {
  $a = (implode('","', $a));
  return $a;
  }

}
```

However in some of the cells there is description text that contains bullet points; '•'.  When importing these are mangled into â€¢

Is there a way to actually store the bullet point into MySQL?

I have tried

```
iconv( "UTF-8", "UTF-8", $str );
```

and also setting the local language to en.US UTF8

---

Comment: `Is there a way to actually store the bullet point into MySQL?` Set the desired column (or table or database) to have the charset of `utf8mb4`. By default in MySQL, it is `latin1` which has no Unicode support.

Comment: @Jon.Frenchtoast Thanks for the idea, but everything is already set to utf8_general_ci

Comment: actually @Jon.Frenchtoast you reminded me; $conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');  Thanks for your help!